# state is null - redux toolkit access state with extraReducers but no reducer

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using `createAsyncThunk` from `@reduxjs/toolkit` to handle my state with `extraReducers`

```
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "accounts/login",
  async (data, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    const csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");
    try {
      let res = await axios({
        url: "mylogin/url",
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
        },
        data: {
          username: data.user_name,
          pwd: data.password,
        },
      });
      return res.data;
    } catch (err) {
      return rejectWithValue(err.response.status);
    }
  }
);

const loginSlice = createSlice({
  name: "login",
  initialState: {
    isLoggedIn: false,
    pending: null,
    error: null,
    userInfo: {
      name: "",
      pwd: "",
      email: "",
    },
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [loginUser.pending]: state => {
      state.pending = true;
      state.error = false;
    },
    [loginUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.pending = false;
      state.isLoggedIn = true;
      state.userInfo = action.payload;
    },
    [loginUser.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.pending = false;
      state.error = true;
    },
  },
});
```

then in the `index_store.js` I configured my store:

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    login: loginSlice.reducer,
  },
});

export default store;
```

I used also the provider in my `index.js`

```
<Provider store={store}>
...
</Provider>
```

then I tried to access my state variable `isLoggedIn` in my component

```
const isLoggedIn = useSelector(state => state.auth.isLoggedIn);
```

but I got this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
```

Comment: Which line throw this error? Show the full error stack. And try `useSelector(state => state.login.isLoggedIn);`?

Comment: I don't know if the line number really correspond to my code : `react.development.js:1614 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at useContext (react.development.js:1614:21)
    at useReduxContext (useReduxContext.js:28:71)
    at useSelector (useSelector.js:136:28)
    at eval (App.js:20:76)
    at Object../src/components/App.js (main.js:2:1016645)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:2:2606419)
    at eval (index.js:8:73)
    at Object../src/index.js (main.js:2:1020267)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:2:2606419)
    at main.js:2:2607272`

Comment: but the bunduled code generated by webpack in `App.js:20:76` is the following : `const isLoggedIn = (0,react_redux__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useSelector)(state => state.login.isLoggedIn);`

Comment: Yeah I change `auth` to `login` and always the same error

Comment: Can you create a minimal, reproducible example using codesandbox?